# GitLab get files from repository

Tags: git, gitlab

I have around twenty repositories. Each repository contains multiple files (around 20.000). I need a method to get some specific files from any of this twenty repositories.

Example: I need the file 2 from Y, file 5 from Z and file 1 and 2 from K.

Is there any method to obtain this files directly without download them as individual if the files I need are always the same? (I can not modify the structure of the repositories)

Also this files need to be updated on the server after I modify them.

Comment: Why not just clone all repositories and commit the changes?

Comment: Because I will lose a great amount of time trying each time to get what files I need and then stay for each repository to commit the changes. I need something like "I push a button and get all of that". If a large amount of people will try to do this individually it will result in a slow production rate. I already mention it that I know what files I need. Some terminal commands to get the files are really slow and boring to write each time especially when there are hundreds or thousand of files that I need to use.

Comment: But you want to check out some files, change them and have the changes be reflected in GitLab?

Comment: In essence yes. The system will work like this: I have a project that needs this files. I get the files, build/compile/modify the project. I update the modified files back from where they came. If in the process will appear new files they will be put in the projects individual repository (this part is not a concern now).

Comment: A solution was to make each project that needs some files in the same repository as the files he needs and just to use only one repository for one project. But I figure it out it is extremely possible that multiple projects to need the same files. And if I modify one of this files the same file from another repository to not be updated. Also there will be too much fragmentation. Too many repositories are not a good thing.

Comment: What kind of files are they?

Comment: Mostly project files (extensions like .cpp, .h, .pro, .pri, .proj). I do not know what matters that much. Each file is around 20 kb and I have around 40 Gb of files. Do you know a solution?